# Do "if" statements affect in the time complexity analysis?

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity-theory

According to my analysis, the running time of this algorithm should be N<sup>2</sup>, because each of the loops goes once through all the elements. I am not sure whether the presence of the `if` statement changes the time complexity?

```
for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
    for(int j=1; j<N; j++){

        System.out.println("Yayyyy");
        if(i<=j){
            System.out.println("Yayyy not");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `if` is just a statement; it would only affect the coefficient which is lost when using Landau notation. *O* is an upper-bound on asymptotic growth, anyways.

Comment: No, the dominant operation is still printing.

Comment: how do u know that s the dominant operation?

Comment: What do you mean by running time? Do you mean that? Or do you mean [Big O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)?

Comment: @DarthVader I just mean that the printing will occur each iteration of the loops.

Comment: @squiguy yeah, but one will happen ones every iteration and the other for roughly half. Besides which, that affects the time, but not the time complexity, which is not the same thing at all.

Comment: @JonHanna I thought he was talking about the time complexity.

Comment: @squiguy He was. I thought you were talking about the dominant operation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- *Tp*: time it takes to print a constant text to standard output.
- *Ti*: time it takes for all other operations inside the inner loop (predicate evaluation etc.).
- *To*: time it takes for all operations inside the outer loop except the execution of inner loop (initializing counters etc.).
- *Tc*: time it takes for setting up the process and every other bookkeeping

Total running time will be *Tc + N x (To + NxTi + N/2xTp)*.

This is equal to *Tc + NxTo + (Nx(N/2)) x (2Ti + Tp)* which is bounded by *K x (N^2)* for values of *K > Ti + Tp/2* as *N* goes to infinity. This boundary makes the time complexity still *O(N^2)*.

No, the *if* statement does not change the time complexity in this example.

Comment: Consider that, there are 100 if statements in the above example, (without else block) won't it affect the overall time complexity of the program at some point? If yes, then what could be that point? I know it would be bad programming practice or might be silly to put so many conditions but I am just asking for better understanding.

Comment: @Akshit: Time complexity is a measure of how the running time changes with respect to input size, it's not an absolute measure of the running time itself. Adding more conditional statements inside this loop will definitely increase the running time, but the rate at which running time increases with respect to input size N is still governed by O(N^2).

Answer (score 3):

No. Consider that time-complexity describes time asymptotically - we absorb lower time-complexities into the higher.

`O(n²)` means `k × n² + c` where it's assumed that `c` is so low that we don't care about it.

These are the constant effects, a certain amount of overhead on the whole thing (c) and a certain amount of cost per whatever our complexity is. One `n²` algorithm will beat another `n²` algorithm if it has a lower `k`, or if they're equal, a lower `c`. Also, O(n²) is the same as O(1) for sufficiently low values of n (and we normally won't care, but the `k` of each could be massively different, and also if we do each m times then while O(n²m) beats O(m), if n is low that's not what's really compared)..

Anyway, this is a deliberate over-simplification, because `k` and `c` might not really be constant, just as good as constant. Hence if something was really `O(n² + log(n))`, we'd call it `O(n²)`, because who cares about that little `log(n)` when we've an `n²` to worry about?

So. Looking at your case. We do the outer loop, `n` times. For each of those, we do the inner loop `n-1` times. For each of those inner loops we do the first print (any variance in cost is not related to `n` in any way, so essentially constant) and the test. The test succeeds roughly half the time, resulting in the cost of the second print that often.

So the total cost is:

```
cost of setting up everything +
n × cost of looping + 
(n - 1) × cost of loop +
(n × (n - 1)) × cost of print +
(n × (n - 1)) × cost of test +
(n × (n - 1)) / 2 × cost of print.
```

Assigning values to the constants above, we get:

```
k +
n × a +
(n - 1) × b +
(n × (n - 1)) × c +
(n × (n - 1)) × d +
(n × (n - 1)) / 2 × e.

=

k +
n × a +
(n - 1) × b +
(n × (n - 1)) × (c + d + (e / 2))
```

Now, since `c + d + e / 2` is itself constant, that can become:

```
n × a + (n - 1) × b + (n × (n - 1)) × c + k
```

Or to re-order, in order of highest order first:

```
(n × (n - 1)) × c + (n - 1) × b + n × a + k
```

If n is high enough for us to give a damn, then n is proportionally so close to n - 1 that we might as well consider them the same (another aspect of time complexity describing things asymptotically, that is as n approaches ∞ and hence the difference between n² and (n × (n - 1)) approaches 0). Hence:

```
n² × c + n × b + n × a = n² × c + n × (b + a) + k
```

Again, b + a is itself constant, so it's equivalent to:

```
n² × k + n × c + a
```

And now we do what was mentioned earlier of absorbing lower time orders, who cares about `n × c`, never mind a? If n is high enough for us to care at all, then it's all about `n²`. In comparison, we might as just consider the difference to the overall overheads as noise and treat it as:

```
n² × k + c
```

Or in other words, as:

```
O(n²)
```

So yes, you were bang on it to begin with, and the if statement doesn't affect the complexity.

Considering this, we can note that it's possible for time complexity to hide what we really care about. If for example, we had a O(n²) algorithm were this sort of analysis found a time cost of `n² × k + n × c` were k amounted to 200µs and c amounted to 15s, then until n is greater than 750000 it's actually the per-n bit that costs, rather than the per-n² bit. At lower n it's closer to what we'd expect from O(n) than from O(n²).

The reason time-complexity is useful, is a combination of so large a disparity being rare, and that we care about time, and hence about time-complexity, more when n gets higher (you could hide some horrible O(n!) monstrosity in your code that you call once in a blue moon, with three elements and just not care). Hence to bring about real-world improvements we ideally want to reduce the time complexity, or failing that reduce the highest level constant k (or in other words, if you can start doing things n log n times instead of n² times then do, otherwise reduce the cost of that thing you're doing n² times rather than something else you're doing n times).

In other words, it helps us focus on what normally mattres.

Answer (score 0):

No, the if doesn't affect the complexity.

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity is the same, you will print Yayyyy N^2 times.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Runtime is still O(N^2).

Long answer: The cost of the conditional check can safely be "added" to the weight of the println operation, the same as if instead of doing one println(), you had two println()'s. (Regarding the example, bear in mind that the cost of I/O operations like println vastly outweigh simple integer comparisons.)

Perhaps you could say that the println() call costs "1 operation", and the comparison is "0.0001 operation", so the total cost would be "(1.0001 * N)^2 operations instead of just N^2. You've also cut the number of println()'s in half, so we can say you're at (1.0001 * N) ^ 2 / 2 operations. This is still O(N^2), even though that for a given value of N you may have halved the runtime by only printing half the entries.

In general, the cost of the comparison should be added to the cost of the operations within the branch(es) resulting from that comparison. When both if() {} and else {} are present, it can be more difficult to measure runtime. A tactic here is to estimate runtime as if the most expensive operation occurs *every time*; or, if the runtime of a single branch is not readily knowable, estimate as though *both* operations occur with every loop iteration. If those operations are both O(1), the order of your runtime remains O(N^2) since you're scaling linearly.

Comment: Even if the comparison took "1 operation": `(2N)^2` = `4N^2` which is still `N^2` complexity.

Answer (score -1):

of course, if you are working with comparison based algorithm, that s what u count right?

so in your case, you are looking at O(n<sup>2</sup>), because your if statement is being executed almost n<sup>2</sup> times.

For non comparison algorithms you count whatever is your main operation.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan he typed `O(n**2)`. Notice the italicized text.